# Efficient merge of two list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

How to efficiently merge two lists efficiently?
Following is the code which gives incorrect results. Not sure. Why?

```
a = [[]] * 5
b = [[1], [] , [], [2], []]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if b[i]:
        a[i] += b[i]
```

Expected output:

```
[[1], [], [], [2], []]
```

Acutal output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Result can be corrected by rewriting `a[i] += b[i]` to `a[i] = a[i] + b[i]`. However, I believe it would highly inefficient as it will result in creating a whole new list. FYI, each list will traversed a large numbers to need to be cache friendly if possible.

Comment: by `a=[[]]*5` you are just creating same copy of of list. do it explicitly like `[[] for _ in range(5)]`

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the duplicate question, you're just referencing the same list copy for each element in `a`. You could also do this to get your desired output:

```
>>> [x + y for x, y in zip(a, b)]
[[1], [], [], [2], []]
```

Comment: OP asked for an efficient one. Your suggested solution requires the creation of a new list. Maybe this will align more with desire of OP `for i in range(0, len(a)):     a[i].extend(b[i])`

Comment: That works, too. My one-liner's not necessarily "inefficient," however. Depends on what your definition of the term is :)